# flutter how to change the color of a button on a click

Tags: flutter, colors, onpress, materialbutton

I am trying to change the color of the button when I click on it. Can you help me because I really can't do it. Thank you.

```
 Container(

        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              new MaterialButton(
                  child: new Text("1"),
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                splashColor: Colors.red,
                  onPressed:  (){
                    test=0;
                    test=1;



},




 ),
              new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("2"),
                  color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    onPressed: (){
                    test=0;
                    test=2;

},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
Color mySplashColor=Colors.blue; //define in build function or state class

splashColors: mySplashColor,
onPressed(){
setState(){
splashColors=Colors.red;
}
}
```

Comment: Hello actually I want the button to change color completely once it is pressed and not a spash thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by using state. The first thing you should do is to transform your widget into a [stateful widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

After that you set a state variable of type Color called buttonColor to have the default value of "Colors.greenAccent". You then set your MaterialButton color property to this variable.

The only thing to do now is to use () => setState(() => buttonColor = Colors.red ) as the button onPressed property.